# Can't connect to project in TFS 2010

Tags: explorer

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7. When I'm trying to connect to tfs server, it shows me the list of projects correctly, but in the Team Explorer the project node is empty.

I can connect to the same project, using the same credentials from other machine in the same network. I also can go to the sharepoint site for that project. I'm just unable to connect to it using Team Explorer.

It doesn't give me any errors, there is nothing in the logs on my machine or on the server. I disabled firewall, checked all of the settings and credentials, nothing helped.

Does anybody know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you don't have any projects selected.  Click right button at the top of the Team Explorer window (Connect to Team Project).  Select your server from the dropdown and select the projects you want in the right pane.

Answer (score 0):

Those who are facing the above issue when connecting from Visual Studio 2010 with TFS, please install the following.
Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010
Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR
([Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082))